# APK install error ("package with that name and different signature"), but certificate info is the same

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have an update to my app that I packaged with the same key as my original app, but when I try to run the APK on my device (emailed to myself), I get this error:

"Application not installed. Package with that name and different signature already installed."

But I used keytool to compare the certificate fingerprints of the META-INF/*APP*.RSA files of both the original apk and the new one, and they match.

I definitely don't want users to have to uninstall and reinstall the app in order to get this update.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a debug version on your device, rather than the production one?

Comment: I removed and reinstalled from the Play store.  I do have a debug version installed as well, but that has a different package name, so that shouldn't affect it right?

Comment: Yes, if the debug edition has a different package name, from Android's standpoint that's a completely separate app. Did you increase your `android:versionCode`?

Comment: Yes, I increased the version name and code.

Comment: Also removed the debug version in case it was causing some issues.  Same error.  But am I right in assuming that if the certificate fingerprints match from the RSA files, then I'm using the right keystore/key?

Comment: I expect that you'll get the same error this way, but you could try using **`adb install`** to install the app via USB cable. If that works, then the APK that you are downloading is not what you think it is, due to caching or something. "But am I right in assuming that if the certificate fingerprints match from the RSA files, then I'm using the right keystore/key?" -- that sounds plausible, but I have never researched that point, sorry.

Comment: Tried adb install, but got the failure message (Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS])

Comment: @user3241964 did you solve this? I have same issue